# How to delete entire folder + contents in a for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Part of a script I'm working on requires recursively looping through all subfolders and deleting all directories that match a specific name like 'foo'

So far I've got this

```
FOR /r "topDir" %%G in (foo) DO (
    echo %%G
    rmdir /s /q %%G
)
```

it's echo-ing out the absolute path of all the folders I need deleted,
but I'm getting a *The system cannot find the file specified* error?

Comment: What is the exact output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `FOR /R` you'll list only the files. To list/iterate trhough the directories recursively you'll need `FOR /D /R` (mind that the switches must be in the same order).Also to list corectly the folders you mandatory need at least one wildcard symbol (`*` or `?`):

```
FOR /d /r "topDir" %%G in (*foo*) DO (
    echo %%G
    rmdir /s /q "%%G"
)
```